# How to loop several variables in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, multiple-variable-return

I want to loop over seventeen variables at the same time in different lists. Zip does not work since I want to loop the second over all the others.

For example: I have the variables a, b, c and resp. lists `al=(0,1)`, `bl=(0,1,2)` and `cl=(0,1,2,3)`; I want the result to be like

a b c

0 0 0

0 1 0

0 0 1

0 1 1

...

(there should be `len(al)*len(bl)*len(cl)` outcomes).
The option I am trying to avoid is to write 17 loops, one on top of the other.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `itertools.product()`. " *Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops* " https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you!!